# Opportunity Standard Object missing from Object Manager. How is that possible?

Tags: opportunity, error, standard-objects

I am supporting a charity in making their system more effective (NPSP) and in Object Manager Opportunity is not visible at all. Has anyone seen anything similar? How can I fix it? I want to use Opportunity to manage their memberships.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the NPSP Donations are the same thing as Opportunity. The object just has a different label on it.

Comment: +1 Typing in Donation in the search box in object manager will find it.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Found it.  It has been relabelled to fundraising for this charity.

Comment: You're welcome. If you're going to assist this charity, I'd recommend you go through the NPSP related Trailhead modules in the [Administer Nonprofit Success Pack Trail](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/content/learn/trails/nonprofit_fundraising). There's also a Trail titled [Manage Volunteers for Nonprofits](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/content/learn/trails/nonprofit_volunteer) and an [NPSP documentation wiki](https://powerofus.force.com/articles/Best_Practice_Business_Process/Configure-and-Customize-NPSP).